# Multiple `FILE`s appending to the same file

Tags: c, stdio

What does the POSIX and/or C standard say about multiple `FILE` structures in append mode which point to the same place in the file system? Specifically, each `FILE` will be flushed after each write to it. For example, in this code:

```c
FILE *a = fopen("foo", "a");
FILE *b = fopen("foo", "a");
fputc('a', a);
fflush(a);
fputc('b', b);
fflush(b);
fclose(a);
fclose(b);
```

Will the contents of `foo` always be `ab`, or is the result indeterminate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C Standard has this language:

> **7.21.5.3 The `fopen` function**
>
> ...
>
> Opening a file with append mode (’a’ as the first character in the `mode` argument) causes all subsequent writes to the file to be forced to the then current end-of-file, regardless of intervening calls to the `fseek` function. In some implementations, opening a binary file with append mode (’b’ as the second or third character in the above list of `mode` argument values) may initially position the file position indicator for the stream beyond the last data written, because of null character padding.

I think this clearly specifies that the posted code should result in the file containing `ab` after execution, as long as the file did not exist prior or was empty and text files do not have bizarre behavior such as automatic appending of newline markers.

I the file was opened in binary mode instead, the contents should definitely be `ab`.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the file in this example will always be `ab`.

Comment: _[Answers do not have to be wordy to be good](https://www.azquotes.com/quotes/topics/brevity.html)_.  This answer, albeit terse, answers the question: _Will the contents of foo always be ab, or is the result indeterminate?_ accurately.  The down-voter should retract their down vote.

Comment: @ryyker Can't. Besides, this doesn't answer "What does the POSIX and/or C standard say about multiple `FILE` structures in append mode which point to the same place in the file system?"